# Many to Many relationship with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, relationship

I have the following tables:

Posts `{id, title, description}`

Tags `{id, name, description}`

post_tags `{post_id, tag_id}`

In Laravel I have set up the relations like below. I'm not sure how to query my post_tags pivot table. I get an error of:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dev_match.post_tag' doesn't exist (SQL: select `tags`.*, `post_tag`.`post_id` as `pivot_post_id`, `post_tag`.`tag_id` as `pivot_tag_id` from `tags` inner join `post_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `post_tag`.`tag_id` where `post_tag`.`post_id` = 1)
```

Home Controller:

```
  public function getindex(){


          $post = Post::all();
         return view('welcome', compact('post'));

       }
```

home view:

```
@foreach($post as $posts)

    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td> <a href="">{{$posts->tags->name}}</a> </td>
        <td>  </td>
        <td> asked </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>


    @endforeach
```

Tag Model:

```
  public function post()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
}
```

Post Model:

```
    public function tag()
 {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add a model for a pivot table (but you can) and also, you don't need to add an `id` to a pivot table.

Your relations are the ok, but if you want to use `id`, you should add [`withPivot('id')`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) to the relationships

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post')->withPivot('id');
}
```

Comment: I don't understand :?. Is my three tables enough without this withPivot('id')?

Comment: @steven yes, three tables, two models.

Comment: Ahh i understand now. Thank you :)

Comment: That last part you added - withPivot('id') What this for? Also, your saying i dont need an id for the post_tags table? Why is that? I'm just curious.

Comment: `withPivot()` is for custom columns. If you don't want to use `id`, don't use `wthPivot()` and yes, you don't need to add an `id` to a pivot table.

Comment: How can I query this relationship to get the tag title? I have updated my question instead of creating another question.

Comment: @steven you should read the documentation first. You can use few ways. The best way is to use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Comment: I have used eager loading before with one to many relationships but not with a pivot table. I get this error, which I have included above.

Comment: Appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: The pivot table name should be `post_tag`